# Run a install-able Flask project error: could not import ""

Tags: python, flask

I read these guides to create my project.

- [Make the Project Installable](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/install/)
- [Deploying with Setuptools](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/distribute/)

First, creating a tar zip file.I create many files in my project folder.
**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='WebMonitor',
    version='1.0',
    long_description=__doc__,
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,
    install_requires=['Flask>=0.12']
)
```

**MANIFEST.in**

```
include schema.sql
include __init__.py
include auth.py
include blog.py
include db.py
graft static
graft templates
global-exclude *.pyc
```

**setup.cfg**

```
[egg_info]
tag_build = .dev
tag_date = 1

[aliases]
release = egg_info -Db ''
```

Then I run this command **python setup.py release sdist** to build  a release package.

Second, install and run this app.

1. Create a virtual environment with the command **virtualenv env**
2. Activate the env with **env\Scripts\activate**
3. Install the release package by **pip install WebMonitor-1.0.tar.gz**
4. **set FLASK_APP=WebMonitor**
5. Then run my app **flask run -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5001**. I get an error output:

   - Serving Flask app "WebMonitor"
   - Environment: production
     WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
     Use a production WSGI server instead.
   - Debug mode: off
     Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]

   Error: Could not import "WebMonitor".

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

As it is production env
in cmd,

> set FLASK_APP=WebMonitor.py

> set FLASK_ENV=development

Answer (score -4):

First ensure that you are at the root of the application file. in case it persist, Deactivate the virtual environment then activate it.